# Why doesn't memory get released to system after large queries (or series of queries) in django?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks

First off, `DEBUG = False` in settings.py, so no, `connections['default'].queries` is not growing and growing until it uses up all of memory.

Lets start off with the fact that I've loaded the `User` table from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` with 10000 users (each named 'test#' where # is a number between 1 and 10000).

Here is the view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse

import time

def leak(request):
    print "loading users"

    users = []
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())
    users += list(User.objects.all())

    print "sleeping"
    time.sleep(10)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

I've attached the view above to the `/leak/` url and start the development server (with DEBUG=False, and I've tested and it has *nothing* to do with running a development server vs other instances).

After running:

```
% curl http://localhost:8000/leak/
```

The runserver process' memory grows to around the size seen from `ps aux` output below and then stays at that level.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dlamotte 25694 11.5 34.8 861384 705668 pts/3    Sl+  19:11   2:52 /home/dlamotte/tmp/django-mem-leak/env/bin/python ./manage.py runserver
```

Then running the above `curl` command above does not seem to grow the instance's memory usage (which I expected from a true memory leak?), it must be re-using the memory?  However, I feel that there is something wrong here that the memory does not get released to the system (however, I understand that it may be better performance that python does NOT release the memory).

Following this, I naively attempted to see if python would release large chunks of memory that it allocated.  So I attempt the following from a python session:

```
>>> a = ''
>>> a += 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' * 10000000
>>> del a
```

The memory is allocated on the `a += ...` line as expected, but when `del a` happens, the memory is released.  Why is the behavior different for django query sets?  Is it something that django is intending to do?  Is there a way to change this behavior?

I've literally spent 2 days debugging this behavior with no idea where to go next (I've learned to use guppy AND objgraph which seem to not point to anything interesting that I can figure out).

**UPDATE:** This could be simply python memory management at work and have nothing to do with Django (suggested on django-users mailing list), but I'd like confirmation by somehow replicating this in python outside of Django.

**UPDATE:** Using python version 2.6.5

Comment: +1. Very interested in answers of this question. I also recognized strange memory leaks with Django over some time on production (DEBUG=False as well and even with very simple apps/projects).

Comment: What happens if you `del users`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using (for both the server and the command line test)? Older versions don't release memory allocated for objects back to the system, so if your local version is 2.5 or later, but your server is running 2.4, that may be your problem. Single large allocations (like your big string) may also bypass the allocator - see what happens with something like `([[]] * 10**6)` instead.

Comment: With lots of small objects, you can also see memory fragmentation problems, so even the more recent allocators are unable to free up complete chunks to return to the OS. As an experimenting, using the big list from my previous comment, grab a reference to every 10th object `x = seq[::10]` or so, then kill the original list and see how much memory you give back to the OS (likely very little).

Comment: My example in the above comments is incorrect - I posted a corrected version as an answer.

Comment: @chris nothing actually, that's the problem (`del users` is the same as leaving the scope of the function

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I decided to move my comments into an answer to make things clearer.

Since Python 2.5, the CPython memory allocation tracks internal memory usage by the small object allocator, and attempts to return completely free arenas to the underlying OS. This works most of the time, but the fact that objects can't be moved around in memory means that fragmentation can be a serious problem.

Try the following experiment (I used 3.2, but 2.5+ should be similar if you use xrange):

```
# Create the big lists in advance to avoid skewing the memory counts
seq1 = [None] * 10**6 # Big list of references to None
seq2 = seq1[::10]

# Create and reference a lot of smaller lists
seq1[:] = [[] for x in range(10**6)] # References all the new lists
seq2[:] = seq1[::10] # Grab a second reference to 10% of the new lists

# Memory fragmentation in action
seq1[:] = [None] * 10**6 # 90% of the lists are no longer referenced here
seq2[:] = seq1[::10] # But memory freed only after last 10% are dropped
```

Note, even if you drop the references to `seq1` and `seq2`, the above sequence will likely leave your Python process holding a lot of extra memory.

When people talk about PyPy using less memory than CPython, this is a major part of what they're talking about. Because PyPy doesn't use direct pointer references under the hood, it is able to use a compacting GC, thus avoiding much of the fragmentation problem and more reliably returning memory to the OS.

Comment: The Dropbox team actually gave a really good description of this problem in their Pycon talk (first mentioned in slide shown at 18:00, more detail at ~26:00): http://pycon.blip.tv/file/4878722/

Comment: Could you link to the relevant parts of the source?

Comment: Development version of the object allocator: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Objects/obmalloc.c

Change the "default" segment in the URL to the relevant Python version to get the latest version of the allocator code on that branch.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of applications, language runtimes, and perhaps even some system memory allocators will keep deallocated memory in place for as long as possible with a view to re-using it, purely for performance purposes. In a complex system like Django it could be any number of extensions, possibly implemented in C, which exhibit this behaviour, or it might be Python with some sort of memory pool, or lazy garbage collection.

It could even be the underlying malloc implementation doing this, or your operating system keeping a certain amount of memory space allocated to your process even though the process isn't explicitly using it. Don't quote me on this though - it's been a while since I looked into such things.

On the whole though, if repeating the allocation process after the initial alloc and dealloc does not double the amount of memory used, what you're seeing is not a memory leak but memory pooling. It's only likely to be a problem if you have a lot of processes that contend for a limited amount of memory on that machine.

Comment: Good answer, just not thrilled with a lot of the "hand waving" magically explanation...  I like that ncoghlan gave me an example of how to do repeat the problem, thanks for your input though

Comment: Sadly, a bit of handwaving is necessary, because it's very rare that you get a completely deterministic mapping between resource allocation in a high level language and process memory usage at the OS level these days - the various memory managers have too many optimisations for that. This is why you can't diagnose a memory leak from `ps` or Task Manager alone.

Comment: ncoghlan sees to have explained it in a way that makes sense.  Memory gets fragmented and therefore cannot be free'd by the interpreter.  I'm sure memory managers come into play at some point... but I think you've blown this out of proportion.  The fact is, the memory was fragmented and has nothing to do with anything deeper than that.

Comment: The only reason the memory is fragmented and can't be freed by the interpreter is -because- there's a special case memory manager at work here. And exactly the same issue applies in the system allocator too, depending on the implementation. My answer is just a more general version of what ncoghlan has specifically highlighted.

Comment: After a little more understanding of the problem and re-reading your answer, I up-voted your answer as I think its a good one.  However, you address the total underlying problem and did not specifically help me with mine, so I think ncoghlan helped me much better than you did.  But I do appreciate the answer.