# Free memory in python run time

Tags: python

I have a python server running on tornado , there is request that uses lots of memory (using a gdata library) . I deleted those object after using them and even did gc.collect() , But when i see the system memory using free -m , I could see memory increase in memory when i do those operations using gdata . But the memory does not get freed up , after i delete the object . The memory gets freed up only after the main python program is killed . I want to know if there is any way to free up the memory .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957539/python-memory-not-being-given-back-to-kernel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494178/why-doesnt-memory-get-released-to-system-after-large-queries-or-series-of-quer

Comment: Are you sure you don't keep any reference to those objects ?

Comment: Yes , I dont want reference to those objects.

Comment: You might not want to reference those objects, but the fact that they're not getting deleted suggests that you are still holding a reference to them. Posting some example code will help.