# PostgreSQL: See query results as scan progresses, rather than wait till end and show all

Tags: postgresql

For a simple select query like `select column_name from table_name` on a very large table, is it possible to have the output being provided as the scan of the table progresses?

If I abort the command after sometime, I expect to get output from the select at least thus far.

Think `cat`, which I believe won't wait till it completes the full read of the file.

Does MySQL or other RDBMS systems support this?

Comment: This is -in fact- the standard behaviour. [but the frontend *might* buffer the produced data until it is complete]

Comment: With Python/psycopg2, you can obtain rows as they become ready [using a server-side cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734989/190597).

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL *always* streams the result to the client, and usually it is the client library that collects the whole result set before returning it to the user.

The C API `libpq` has [functionality that supports this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-single-row-mode.html). The main disadvantage with this approach is that you could get a run time error *after* you already have received a some rows, so that's a case you'd have to handle.

The traditional way to receive a query result in parts is to use a *cursor* and fetch results from it. This is a technique supported by all client APIs.

Cursors are probably what you are looking for, and they are supported by all RDBMS I know in some fashion.