# How to use UPDATE/DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF in psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using server-side cursor in PostgreSQL with psycopg2, based on [this well-explained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734989/317971).

```
with conn.cursor(name='name_of_cursor') as cursor:
    query = "SELECT * FROM tbl FOR UPDATE"
    cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        # process row
```

In processing each row, I'd like to update a few fields in the row using PostgreSQL's `UPDATE tbl SET ... WHERE CURRENT OF name_of_cursor` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING)), but it seems that, when the for loop enters and `row` is set, the position of the server-side cursor is in a different record, so while I can run the command, the wrong record is updated.

How can I make sure the result iterator is in the same position as the cursor? (also preferably in a way that won't make the loop slower than updating using an ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why a different record was being updated was because internally psycopg2 does a `FETCH FORWARD 1000` (or whatever the default chunk size is), positioning the cursor at the end of the block. You can override this by fetching one record at a time:

```py
updcursor = conn.cursor()
with conn.cursor(name='name_of_cursor') as cursor:
    cursor.itersize = 1  # to make server-side cursor be in the same position as the iterator
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl FOR UPDATE')
    for row in cursor:
        # process row...
        updcursor.execute('UPDATE tbl SET fld1 = %s WHERE CURRENT OF name_of_cursor', [val])
```

The snippet above will update the correct record. Note that you **cannot** use the same cursor for selecting and updating, they must be different cursors.

### Performance

Reducing the FETCH size to 1 reduces the retrieval performance by a lot. I definitely wouldn't recommend using this technique if you're iterating a large dataset (which is probably the case you're searching for server-side cursors) from a different host than the PostgreSQL server.

I ended up using a combination of exporting records to CSV, then importing them later using `COPY FROM` (with the function [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert)).