# "Memory error" when using pd.read_sql_query method

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to create a dataframe using the data in redshift table.
But I am getting "Memory error" because the data I am fetching is huge in volume.
how to sove this issue, (I found chunking is one option. How to implement chucking) Is there any other library useful for such situations ?
The following is an example code

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host_name,user=usr,port=pt,password=pass,db_name=DB)

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name"
df = pd.read_sql_query(conn,sql_query)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Psycopg2 uses up memory on large select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343240/psycopg2-uses-up-memory-on-large-select-query)

Comment: either stream the rows one by one, or use pyspark