# How to use chucksize function while fetching data from PostgreSQL using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to fetch data from Postgresql using python. I used fetchall function but since the data is huge its not working and taking lot of time so i thought chunksize might help but unable to find any document on it.

Comment: What Postgresql adapter are you using and what have you done so far? Please provide more information

Comment: i am using psycopg2 connector. I have created the connection and created the cursor and by using cur.execute i am sending my SQL to database and using fetchall to get all the data into python memory.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933344/python-postgres-can-i-fetchall-1-million-rows

Comment: There is no chucksize, so no documentation for it.  Pandas has a chunksize.  psycopg2 has itersize.  Both are documented in their respective documentation.