# "SELECT INTO" not allowed in Psycopg2 with postgres when using named cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

Here's a very simple reproducible case that I haven't seen an answer for. If I use no name on the cursor (default), everything works fine. If, however, I use a named cursor, all of a sudden there is an error that select INTO is not allowed. Does anybody know why psycopg2/pg would behave differently for the query syntax between a named and not named cursor in this case?

(note, this is part of a large multi-step query with 2 temporary tables and a full outer join to get a comparison at the end. The objective of using the named cusor is so that the potentially very large end result doesn't use up all of the memory and end up dying. I might have millions of rows returned from the outer join.)

Works:

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select NOW() into temporary table foo")
>>> cur.close()
```

Doesn't work:

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor("diff_query")
>>> cur.execute("select NOW() into temporary table foo")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: SELECT ... INTO is not allowed here
LINE 1: ...URSOR WITHOUT HOLD FOR select NOW() into temporary table foo
```

Comment: Note: I'm using the named cursor as part of the technique to deal automatically with large  potential result sets as described in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199113/psycopg2-leaking-memory-after-large-query/17203872  
Maybe that's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: It is.  From here [Declare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html): "query
   A SELECT or VALUES command which will provide the rows to be returned by the cursor."  `SELECT INTO` is basically `CREATE TABLE AS`.

Comment: yeah, it's definately the wrong thing to do when the query is DDL and is not returning rows to the caller.